# regular hexagon sides as vectors 2

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

Let ABCDEF be regular hexagon.Then $\overline{AB}
 +\overline{AC}+\overline{AD}+\overline{EA}+\overline{FA} =?$

my answer is $3\overline{AB}$
but actually it is $4\overline{AB}$

Comment: Sir my question is whether 3$\over{AB}$  is correct or not and plz elaborate how do u get that 4$\over{AB}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easiest to work in a non-rectangular coordinate system where the axes make a 120° angle with each other. For example put the origin at $A$, $(1,0)$ at $B$ and $(0,1)$ at $F$. Then the coordinates of the corners are
$$ A(0,0) \quad B(1,0) \quad C(2,1) \quad D(2,2) \quad E(1,2) \quad F(0,1) $$
Your sum is then
$$ (1,0) + (2,1) + (2,2) - (1,2) - (0,1) = (4,0) $$

Comment: thx i learnt a new method  but plz sir tell me about 3AB

Comment: @Kimmy: I have no idea how you got $3\overline{AB}$ and therefore can't possibly tell you what you did wrong to get that. Also, I don't appreciate your rude tone here. What have I done to you that would make you 'sir' me?

Comment: I am sorry for my words ...

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\def\v#1#2{\overrightarrow{#1#2}}\v AE = \v BD$, as $ABCDEF$ is regular, hence 
$$ \v AD + \v EA = \v AB + \v BD + \v EA = \v AB $$
On the other hand we have
$$ \v AC + \v FA = \v FC $$
As $ABCDEF$ is regular $\v FC = 2\v AB$, so the sum is 
$$ \v AB + \v AC + \v AD + \v EA + \v FA = \v AB + 2\v AB + \v AB = 4\v AB$$